# angular angular-table dynamic header name

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I use angular and [angular-table](https://github.com/samu/angular-table) to display multiple tables on the same page.

I need to create dynamic table with dynamic header and dynamic content.

[Plunkr her](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Pd3p0FdinYtmAYoIdba)

This is a working example with non dynamic header but I don't find how to make dynamic

**The controller :**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap',"angular-table","angular-tabs"]);

function ListCtrl($scope, $dialog) {

  $scope.cols= ['index','name','email'];
  $scope.list = [
      { index: 1,  name: "Kristin Hill",    email: "kristin@hill.com"    },
      { index: 2,  name: "Valerie Francis", email: "valerie@francis.com"  },
      ...
  ];
  $scope.config = {
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      fillLastPage: true
  };

}
```

**HTML**

```
 <!--  this work -->
<table class="table table-striped" at-table at-paginated at-list="list" at-config="config">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td at-implicit at-sortable at-attribute="name"></td>
          <td at-implicit at-sortable at-attribute="name"></td>
          <td at-implicit at-sortable at-attribute="email"></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

<!-- this fail ... -->
<table class="table table-striped" at-table at-paginated at-list="list" at-config="config">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr> 
          <td ng-repeat='col in cols' at-implicit at-sortable at-attribute="{{col}}"></td> 
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

I am missing some think or it is not possible with this module ?

Did you know another module where you can have dynamic header and pagination ? ( i try also ngTable but have some bug issu with data not being displayed )

Answer (score 0):

Through the below code, you can generate dynamic header

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="accordion-toggle tblHeader">
              <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in columns">{{key}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
              <td ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat="col in key(row)" ng-init="val=row[col]">
              {{val}}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Angular Script

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myControl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').success(function (data) {
            $scope.columns = data[0];
            $scope.rows = data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {

        });

        $scope.key = function (obj) {
            if (!obj) return [];
            return Object.keys(obj);
        }

    });
```